# After Login If I switch to other page (or) Reload/Refresh the page , the website/page is directed to login page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, useselector

After Login or Signup , If I switch to other page the site is automatically directed to Login Page
After Login If I switch to other page (or) Reload/Refresh the page , the website/page is directed to login page

App.js file

```
function App() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        dispatch(
          login({
            uid: authUser.uid,
            photo: authUser.photoURL,
            displayName: authUser.displayName,
            email: authUser.email,
          })
        );
      } else {
        dispatch(logout());
      }
    });
  }, [dispatch]);
  const PrivateRoutes = () => (
    user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth" />
      
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<StackOverflow />} />
            <Route path="/add-question" element={<Question />} />
            <Route path="/question" element={<ViewQuestionFolder />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

End of Code
Code Ended

Comment: You are probably getting the authentication from your server. When you update the page, it has to get the information on the server again. Are you waiting for the information to arrive before checking if the user is authenticated?

Comment: Yes , after authentication / Login I am unable to switch Pages . If I click   add-question page   From Home , it directs me to Login page and after this, If I Login  again it directs me to Home page where I’ll click add-question its goes Back to Login